# Rethinkdb: search a string in whole table (full text search like)

Tags: rethinkdb-python

I'm writing a python flask application in combination with rethinkDB.

snippit structure:

{'Name': ['Gandalf', 'Jackson'], 'street': 'elmStreet'...}

This kind of structure is used multiple times, so basically I have all my keys as a string and my values are either also strings or an array with strings.

So I want a full-text search on this structure without using ElasticSearch or any additional program if it is possible.

Thanks for reading, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue, by using the python search engine whoosh, for it no additional program is needed.